# Chrome select element erratic

Tags: html, css, forms, google-chrome, drop-down-menu

I have a problem which I really hate.

In Chrome all my select elements in my forms are erratic.

When I click on the select and then move cursor down then the
focus jumps on the elements very strangely.

If I wait about 1 second after clicking on the select box then
the behaviour is OK, the focus is on the same element as the cursor (which is not the
case if I don't wait)

Just pure HTML no JS.

All forms are Zend Forms.

FF, IE, Opera are OK

Thanks,

David

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have found it.

I my CSS

```
-webkit-transition: all 0.5s linear;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s linear;
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s linear;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s linear;
    transition: all 0.5s linear
```

changed to 0.01 and now everything is OK.

Regards